# How to dismiss UIImagePickerController on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a `UIImagePickerController`.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];    
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 500, 500) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

When I use any photo from gallery class delegate `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"inside Delegate image pick");

    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

That is working fine, but I'm having trouble with the `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` delegate method.

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    NSLog(@"inside Cancel ");

    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

`imagePickerControllerDidCancel` is never called, and I don't know why. How do I dismiss the popover when the user clicks cancel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` does not get call it means you need to implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Example

```
@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```